# Как сделать, чтобы команда tree не выводила некоторые файлы?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения

Как переписать регулярное выражение из примера ниже, чтобы не выводились дополнительно к файлами `*.*~` ещё и файлы вида `*.pyc`?

```
dzmitry@mycomp:~/myenv/myproj$ tree -I *.*'~'
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── myapp1
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-34.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── myapp1
│   │       ├── form.html
│   │       └── result.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── myproj
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

8 directories, 29 files
dzmitry@mycomp:~/myenv/myproj$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ `|` (or) нужно просто экранировать в командной строке linux, иначе она его рассматривает как pipe:

```
tree -I *.*'~'\|*.pyc
```

либо же взять выражение в кавычки:

```
tree -I '*.*'~'|*.pyc'
```